# Data visualization framework for a web server?

Tags: charts, visualization

I need a framework for generating charts for data visualization. I picked up Processing www.processing.org/ but at the moment i can not run that in the "headless" mode from a web server. Is there any other candidate for this domain? What are the options if you need more chart type than what is supported by out-of-the-box solutions

-Bharani

Comment: Can you give a little more detail about what types of chart generation you need to do?

Comment: To update the thread with recent related question (and answers): http://stackoverflow.com/q/9033342/179529

Answer (score 1):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is a option, or a software reporting software tool that does all the footwork of data analysis for you. I can recommend **[i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de)** seeing as how I work for i-net software and all... ;).

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/) for the clientside chart drawing

Great set of OpenSource Silverlight chart has published on CodePlex - Check out http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

[Visifire](http://visifire.com/silverlight_charts_gallery.php) is a free charting library available in Silverlight

And a tutorial [is up here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-1.0-Bar-Chart-Tutorial.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I am now using Graphics2D that comes with JDK. With this you are no longer limited to the chart types - simply concentrate of the data pattern and let Graphics2D do it's job.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/), if you're into calling stuff through the command line, and [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/), if you're using python.